# restrict web application users to specific number of terminals using certificates

Tags: web-applications

Hi
I am developing a cloud based application. It is a niche application, and not a public general consumer facing application. For specific need wrt the nature of the application and also to keep traffic costs low-as this will be a free application, I need to restrict the access for each user to certain number of terminal. IE: each user can use only 1 computer to access the system at any time. But he need not use the same computer every time. He can always log off and login using another computer. Now there are many ways I am considering to implement this. One of them is to use some sort of certificate to identify along with the username.

Questions:
1. Is this possible using any off the shelf technology?
2. Using the existing technologies, how much effort does the user need to go thru? eg:does he have to install anything every time he wants to use another system etc.
3. Any links that provide information about using such a system in a web application?

Must have Requirement:
Should be OS/browser independent

Please share your general experience if you have faced such scenario during development of web application.

PS: Please note that I am not restricting people using the application, but the terminals using the application. IE several people might use the application using same credentials. But at any time, only one terminal can access the application with a given credential. Another scenario might be where an account specifically require to use 2 terminals. In this case 2 different terminal can use the application at any given point of time but not more.

Comment: The basic problem here is that it is difficult to prevent one person pretending to be two different people. Actually, there is a new effort by the US government to create an "[internet ID card](http://www.engadget.com/2011/01/09/obama-administration-moves-forward-with-unique-internet-id-for-a/)" to prove identity online. This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: hmmm..the internet ID card seems to be an overkill for my application and ofcourse it is not yet ready to use now. I  was looking for something that is in use. And just to clarify, I am not trying to restrict people, but computers using the application.

Comment: Are you working in a particular language / framework? Some frameworks make it very easy to restrict this sort of thing, while others require you to jump through hoops.

Comment: I think you have a basic misunderstanding. As you define your needs, you want to control user sessions, not terminals.

You want to limit users to have one concurrent session on the service.

If you want an "off the shelf" solution, you should give us details about your install: web server, development language, framework...

Comment: @cdeszaq: I am using asp.net mvc

Comment: @itorres: Not sessions. It is very easy to do If it is just session. But, if I login in to the server from 3 different browsers(or browser sessions) simultaneously from same system, it will be considered as 3 different sessions. I dont want to restrict the user to one session. If the user signs up for 2 clients. He can have any number of session, provided he uses only maximum of two client computers simultaneously.